# facebook message icon appears behind menu - can't figure out which id or class to give z-index to

Tags: css, facebook, z-index

I've just noticed that on my site when you click the facebook like button and the little windows opens for you to post a comment, that window appears behind my drop down menu.

I have a z-index of 1000 on the dropmenu so thats why it appears in front but I'm buggered if I can figure out which div id or class to put a higher z-index on which will make it work. I've tried all types of combos but haven't stumbled across the correct answer yet. I'm not so strong with css

Any wizards out there know the answer?

site: https://www.traditionalirishgifts.com

thanks

Comment: Do you have an url to the site?

Comment: oops, I'm stoopid, its in the OP now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu element width the id `dropMenu` has a `z-index` of `3000`. You need a higher `z-index` for your facebook button.

On the `fb:like` element, add `z-index` of `3001` or higher.

```
<fb:like style="z-index: 3100;" href="http://www.traditionalirishgifts.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" class="fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget"></fb:like>
```

OR in your css-file

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment {
    z-index: 3100;
}
```

Comment: how did you figure out it was .fb_edge_widget_with_comment, I use a developer toolbar thing and I can't see where that div appears amongst all the rest!

Comment: I use chrome, just right click on the like button and inspect, and you will find a lot of elements, and if you are familiar with facebook like buttons you know that fb:like is the parent element for the button. And with the inspector you can easily see that the fb:like-element has the class fb_edge_widget_with_comment.

Answer (score 0):

For the facebook send popup I needed the to adjust the following

> .fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_send_button_form_widget{
>      z-index: 1001000 !important;
>   }

For the Like popup I needed
`.fb_iframe_widget {
    z-index:1001000;
}`